# Is a construction/definition a premise in a logical argument that a proof is?

Tags: logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Mean_Value_Theorem

A proof is a logical argument with the hypotheses as premises and the desired result as conclusion. In proof 1 as given, the premises have been left unstated (they are stated in the statement of the theorem, but not in proof 1). That's fine with me. But then we construct a function:

F(x) = f(x) + hx.

Now, my question is, are we to consider the statement F(x) = f(x) + hx as an additional premise, besides the other premise(s) (which have been explicitly stated in the statement of the theorem)?

If the above-mentioned statement is indeed to be considered as a premise of the argument that the proof is, I think there will be a problem. The problem is that then the proof will have the statement as a premise in addition to the premise(s) which occur in the statement of the theorem. This will make it appear that the conclusion (desired result) has been derived taking into consideration the set-of-premises-including-the-mentioned-statement, whereas we want to show that the desired result holds when the set-of-premises-not-including-the-statement F(x) = f(x) + hx holds.

Needless to say, I am trying to understand not only in the context of this proof but the wider context of *any* such situation.

I am a self-learner, so please be understanding.

Comment: No, the assumption of the Th is the existence of function $f(x)$. With it, we can construct a new function $F(x)=f(x)+hx$; the existence of $F(x)$ is quite obvious: its construction satisfies the general definition of *function*.

Comment: Then we prove the fact that $F(x)$ is continuous and differentiable.

Comment: I would say that it is an immediate consequence of the premises.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'd got some fundamentals messed up.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The Wikipedia entry https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theorem says that a proof of a theorem is a logical argument. In a logical argument each statement is either a premise or the conclusion.  So, where would 'immediate consequence of the premises' fit in?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument%E2%80%93deduction%E2%80%93proof_distinctions It appears that the "argument" that the Wikipedia article on theorems refers to is  'deduction', not a premise-conclusion argument. Probably, Wikipedia is not entirely consistent on what a proof is.

Comment: Yes of course, if you want to be so detailed in your proof, you have to split it into a sequence of sub-proofs: usually many Lemma and one final Theorem. Thus, Lemma 1 will be: given a function $f(x)$ and a real number $h$, we can always construct a new function $F(x)=f(x)+hx$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can think of the "premises" of the proof to be solid and unchangeable facts that can be used as necessary. However, more of these "premises" can be constructed as you move through the proof.

In a construction of something of the type $F(x) = f(x) + h(x)$, this is essentially using the existing premises to create a new premise which can also be leveraged in a proof setting. Of course, this new added information must be logically consistent with all the previously assumed information.

Usually, you would have to argue for the existence or acceptability of a statement of that form, but in this case, its clear that such a function can exist and can be defined in this way without any issue.

Comment: In general, it is not true that if a conclusion follows from n premises, then it also follows from n-1 premises. If the statement F(x) = f(x) + hx is taken to be a premise, then won't this imply that the premise(s) representing the condition(s) of the theorem, is/are possibly by themselves insufficient to guarantee the truth of the conclusion of the theorem statement?

Comment: The statement $F(x) = f(x) + h(x)$ is just an extension of the premises. The premises are in fact sufficient, because they lead to a logically consistent new piece of information. If what you are insinuating is that you can't use any new constructions or arguments within your proof at the risk of using something outside your premises, this is incorrect, you can. Besides, your line of reasoning here is relatively uninformed. I would recommend reading a text on logic in mathematics, or work on proof writing. You would also find texts on foundational mathematics (axioms and the like) interesting.